# An algebraic question from math olympiad .

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

There is a 1 gm weight on each side of a balance. If Harry Potter casts a spell with his magic wand on any of the weights, then the mass of that particular weight doubles, but the other weight remains unchanged. How many masses between 1 and 1000 gm inclusive can be measured using this balance?

Please give some hints, not solution to solve this question . Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an edit): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What have you tried to solve it? Hint: numbers of the form $2^m-2^n$, m and n are whole numbers

Comment: Maybe you can type it instead of just sharing a screenshot. People will be more receptive.

Comment: Help with formatting math: see math.stackexchange.com/help/notation and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto

Comment: Any thoughts on the answers that have been posted, rahid?

Comment: It's not polite to post and run, rahid. Please engage with the users who are trying to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious hint is to reduce the maximum number from 1,000 to, say, 10, or even 5, and then enumerate the possible cases. Double one side and you can weigh 2-1=1g, then double twice and you can weigh 4-1=3g, then double the other side and you can weigh 4-2=2g, double the other side again and you can weigh 8-2=6g, and so on. If you just enumerate all the possibilities for a lower number, the way to solve the problem for the general case should become fairly obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You can weigh amounts $2^a-2^b$ for $a>b\ge 0,$ and no other amounts. If $a\ge 11$ and $b\le a-1$ then $2^a-2^b\ge 2^{10}>1000.$ So the answer may seem to be the number of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ with $1\le a\le 10$ and $0\le b\le a-1,$ minus the $5$ pairs $(10, b)$ with $0\le b\le 4$ that give $2^a-2^b>1000$. BUT you must not assume without proof that there are no duplicates. If $(a,b)\ne (a',b')$ is it possible that $2^a-2^b=2^{a'}-2^{b'}?$