# How do I solve this question regarding algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

There is a $1 \mathrm{gm}$ weight on each side of a balance. If Harry Potter casts a spell with his magic wand on any of the weights, then the mass of that particular weight doubles, but the other weight remains unchanged. How many masses between 1 and 1000 gm inclusive can be measured using this balance?

**Attempt by Suzu Hirose**

The maximum number from 1,000 to, say, 10, or even 5, and then enumerate the possible cases. Double one side and you can weigh 2-1=1g, then double twice and you can weigh 4-1=3g, then double the other side and you can weigh 4-2=2g, double the other side again and you can weigh 8-2=6g, and so on. If you just enumerate all the possibilities for a lower number, the way to solve the problem for the general case should become fairly obvious.

Comment: Rather than reposting the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4480531/an-algebraic-question-from-math-olympiad) you should [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4480531/edit) the original one with what you added here.

Comment: Just realized that the attempt here is identical to Suzu Hirose's answer to the other question.

Answer (score 4):

In your last post you asked for a hint, so here it is. A weight can be measured exactly when it is the difference between two powers of two. Therefore in each interval $[2^k,2^{k+1})$ there will be exactly $k+1$ measurable weights, for $2^{k+1}-1,2^{k+1}-2,...,2^{k+1}-2^k$.

Comment: sir I stuck here . What will be the answer?